# How to assign null value in dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to send to server parameters like this:

```
"searchConditions": {
     "firstNameLastName": "My Name",
     "email": null,
}
```

I'm trying to send like this:

```
let searchParameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "firstNameLastName": self.byNameField.text!,
        "email": ""
}
```

but server sees that `"email": ""` as `email=`

When I try to set `"email": nil` it gives me an error:

```
Nil is not compatible with expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'
```

How can I send "null" value to my server?

Comment: Did you try to ignore email param if it's null? Maybe you have to discuss with server team about null value.

Comment: WHY would you want to send nil, or null to server, whats the purpose? Dictionary values can't have nil.

Comment: simply don't put any value in the dictionary for email. When you access that key of the dictionary you will get back nil. In that case send the literal string null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John,

You can use NSNull() to insert null in dictionary,

like

```
let test : [String : AnyObject] = ["test" : NSNull()]
```

When you print the value of test key you will get

```
po test["test"]
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  - Some : <null>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C:

```
"email" = [NSNull null]
```